# How to launch my Android / IOS app from a link

Tags: android, ios, url, cordova, phonegap-build

I have made android/IOS application using PHONEGAP BUILD its working fine for mi. Now i want to open that Application through link. So that I can provide this link to customers through mail and messages so they can directly open application by clicking on link. For this what changes i have to do in my config file. And how to make that link to open a application? please help mi out.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you must go to YourApp-Info.plist, go to (or create if you don't have it yet) "URL types" Array -> Add one item with the following fields: 
 1) URL identifier - String - "your app identifier"
 2) URL Schemes - Array
     2.1) Item 0 - String - "yourApp"

The link you send must match the URL Scheme, like so : "yourApp://whatever". By doing the above steps, the iOS will register your app to be one of the apps to respond to the "yourApp" URL scheme, just like facebook responds to "fb://"

You can find more information here:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Once your app has been opened from an URL scheme, you can continue with the development in your AppDelegate.m in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

if (url) {
    NSString *urlScheme = [url scheme];
    if (urlScheme != nil && [urlScheme isEqualToString:@"yourApp"]) {

        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithString:url.path];
        NSString *urlHost = [NSString stringWithString:url.host];
    ....
```

Here you can parse the rest of your URL, in order to bring the user to different screens or any other action.

Comment: This doesn't apply to [PhoneGap Build](http://build.phonegap.com) as it involves modifying the Cordova source code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a Custom URL Scheme in your config.xml. This is currently only supported by iOS apps on PhoneGap Build. [From the PGB docs](http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml):

> iOS Only. Allows registration of custom URL schemes.
>
> ```
> <gap:url-scheme name="com.acme.myscheme" role="None">  
>     <scheme>pgbr</scheme>
>     <scheme>pgbw</scheme>
> </gap:url-scheme>
> ```
>
> - Multiple gap:url-scheme elements can be present.
> - name, optional, defaults to the application bundle id. This has to be unique. If a
>     duplicate is found the build will fail.
> - role must be Editor, Viewer,
>     Shell or None, optional, defaults to None.
> - at least one scheme must be
>     present.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. One more question, What is this scheme? is it necessary? By this i will get URL? How? And how to call that URL? can you please tell me some example..

Comment: On the PGB docs link I posted above, there is another link to the [iOS Developer Documentation on URL Schemes (Communicating with Other Apps)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18).